# DOMDocument wrappers?

Tags: php, domdocument

Are there any HTML parsers written in PHP that use DOMDocument for parsing?

I'm basically looking for a wrapper class that provides nicer and more natural API than DOMDocument, which is problematic to work with.

Comment: What specifically don't you like about it or find difficult?

Comment: well for example the fact that I need to write a huge amount of code just to get an element with a certain class

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at and learning how to use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [SmartDOMDocument](http://beerpla.net/projects/smartdomdocument-a-smarter-php-domdocument-class/), its fixes a few things like encoding and outputting as string.

I don't know of any other wrappers, but you can use an alternative to DOMDocument:

- [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)
- [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
- [Ganon](http://code.google.com/p/ganon/)

Also, do you realize [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) exists?
It makes it way easier to retrieve values.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/PHP_HTML_DOM_parser/PHPHTMLDOMParser.cc_09-07-2011.php3 is another possibility.